# Function in Parent never called following an $emit from the Child

Tags: vue.js, nodes

I have included an $emit in an axios post of a child component as follows.

```
 axios.post('/api/register', qdata)
  .then((response) => {
   this.$emit('userUpdated', response.data)
  })
```

In the parent component, I have a div element in the html code containing a v-on, which refers to the userUpdated of the $emit.

```
 <div id="username" v-on:userUpdated="nameUpddated($event)">
   <p>{{userid}}</p>
 </div>
```

Finally, the script section of the parent contains the following function called by the v-on.

```
nameUpddated: function (updatedUser) {
  this.userid = updatedUser
}
```

I have validated that the axios returns a proper value in the Child component. However, the function in the parent never gets called.

Comment: Does `div id="username"` is a child component?

Comment: Thank you Anatoly. No, the id does not correspond to the child component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your parent component use **child component name** instead of `div`.

**Edit:** I also added `v-if` to conditionally show the component.

```
 <child-component v-if="isVisible" id="username" v-on:userUpdated="nameUpddated($event)">
   <p>{{userid}}</p>
 </child-component>
```

Also, you need to add a `data` property to show the component conditionally (initially hidden).

```
   data () {
        return {
            isVisible: false
        }
    }
```

*Now, it is up to you at what point you want to show the child component. You would simply change `isVisible` to `true`*.

After making this change, it should work as expected.

---

**Note:** please remember to register the child component properly as well in your parent component:

```
import childComponent from '@/components/childComponent'

export default {
    components: {
        childComponent
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Jakub. Do I need to use the child component name for an $emit to work? The child component is a modal window. If I apply the modification you have suggested, the modal window will be displayed automatically, which I do not want.

Comment: No, for the `$emit` to work you do not need to worry about the component name. You can use `v-if `or `v-show` to conditionally show or hide the component based on some condition. For that you might need a `data` property in your parent component, for example: `isVisible: false` set to `false` initially, then on some button press you could change it to `@click="isVisible=true"`. After that you would add `<child-component v-if=isVisible></child-component>`. You can read more about in the documentation: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#Conditional-Groups-with-v-if-on-lt-template-gt